# Trying to select previous li element of selected li element of ul

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ngfor, string-interpolation

I am iterating over list-items, what I want to achieve is to not have the border-right on the element that is previous(Summary 2) to active li (Mindmap 3), as shown in the **image** it always assigns border to every element in the un-ordered list, I have written this **if** condition that says assign border to all li items having index less then length of un-ordered list, and not to the element that is previous to selected li but it also assigns border-left to that element that is **summary 2** in our case. I think something is wrong with the if condition but I am not been able to figure out what?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" (click)="selectTab(tab)" 
      [class.active]="tab.active"
      [class.border]="(i < tabs.length - 1) && !(tabs[i+1]?.active)">
    <div>
      <div>
        <img class="icon" style="width: 18px;"
             src="../../../assets/icons/{{tab.icon}}.svg">
       {{tab.title}} {{i}}
    </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Css definitions are as follows.

```
.active {
  border: 1px solid #eaeef0;;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  height: 44px;
}

.border {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the css definition for `.active` and `.border`?

Comment: @chris.va.rao edited the Question, css def. added :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not select the previous `li` element to remove the border. Just set the left border instead of right border and modify your CSS as below.

```
li {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
    border-left:none; /*First element should not have a left border*/
}

li.active {
    border-left: none;/*Border definition for active element*/
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understood the Question clearly, I don‘t want to have border-right on previous element of selected element, so in our case summary 2 is previous el and mindmap is the current one.

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat I did understand your question and I feel that your implementation needs a change. instead of removing right border of previous, why not set left border of current? Your CSS needs a change.Give us an online code and I'll fix it